# how to change lowercase to uppercase using Instrument.sendKeyDownUpSync(int keycode) in android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, uppercase, android-instrumentation

I want to send some String to other application in Android, in this case I am using Instrumentation, but it's only read the lowercase.

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
```

How to change Lowercase to Uppercase?
Note : don't using "sendStringSync" method, because it's slow.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
inst.sendStringSync("A");
```

Or

```
Instrumentation inst = new Instrumentation();
KeyEvent keyEvent=new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
inst.sendKeySync(keyEvent);
```

Comment: Yes, I was used it, but it's slow in my other app.